# Why I can't see data at a epoch

Tags: vertica

I inserted data in a table at different `epochs` (committed different rows at different times).

```
badmin@310762407bda(*)=> select a,b,epoch from test;
 a | b | epoch
---+---+-------
 1 | 2 |    38
 3 | 4 |    38
 5 | 6 |    39
 7 | 8 |    40
```

Why does this query fail if I specify `epoch` value of 38 and 39? Why only 40 works? Why `epochs` before `40` don't exist even though the table shows them.

```
dbadmin@310762407bda(*)=> at epoch 38 select * from test;
ERROR 3183:  Epoch number out of range
HINT:  Epochs prior to [40] do not exist. Epochs [41] and later have not yet closed
dbadmin@310762407bda(*)=> at epoch 39 select * from test;
ERROR 3183:  Epoch number out of range
HINT:  Epochs prior to [40] do not exist. Epochs [41] and later have not yet closed
dbadmin@310762407bda(*)=> at epoch 40 select * from test;
 a | b
---+---
 1 | 2
 3 | 4
 5 | 6
 7 | 8
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fire This:

```
SELECT 
  current_epoch
, ahm_epoch
, last_good_epoch
FROM system;
 current_epoch | ahm_epoch | last_good_epoch 
---------------+-----------+-----------------
         37396 |     37395 |           37395
```

I can go `AT EPOCH 37395 SELECT [...]` ...

```
 $ vsql -c "AT EPOCH 37395 SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 5"
        id         | first_name | last_name  |       hire_dt       
-------------------+------------+------------+---------------------
 1.000000000000000 | Arthur     | Dent       | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
 2.000000000000000 | Ford       | Prefect    | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
 3.000000000000000 | Zaphod     | Beeblebrox | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
 4.000000000000000 | Tricia     | McMillan   | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
 5.000000000000000 | Gag        | Halfrunt   | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
```

But not `AT EPOCH 37394 SELECT [...]` ...

```
$ vsql -c "AT EPOCH 37394 SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 5"
ERROR 3183:  Epoch number out of range
HINT:  Epochs prior to [37395] do not exist. Epochs [37396] and later have not yet closed
```

You can't go back behind the Ancient History Mark...
You can, however, use `WHERE epoch<=37394` ....

```
 $ vsql -c "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE epoch < 37394 LIMIT 5"
        id         | first_name | last_name  |       hire_dt       
-------------------+------------+------------+---------------------
 1.000000000000000 | Arthur     | Dent       | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
 2.000000000000000 | Ford       | Prefect    | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
 3.000000000000000 | Zaphod     | Beeblebrox | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
 4.000000000000000 | Tricia     | McMillan   | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
 5.000000000000000 | Gag        | Halfrunt   | 2017-02-05 00:00:00
```